# ThinkingSphinx (and Heroku Flying Sphinx) - getting unknown column error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm working on a Rails app where I use `ThinkingSphinx` for search. It's deployed on `Heroku` where I use their plugin `Flying Sphinx`. On my local development machine it works, but at first I got the same error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError (unknown column: 'question' ...
```

Performing:

```
rake ts:rebuild
```

Was enough to make it work on my local machine. But I continue to get the same error in my production environment despite using:

```
heroku run bundle exec flying-sphinx rebuild
```

The relevant index file looks like this:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :competition, :with => :real_time do
  indexes name
  # This index seems to be causing the error:
  indexes question
  indexes user(:name), as: :idea_user
  indexes taggings.tag(:name), :as => :idea_tags

  has user_id, type: :integer
  has team_id, type: :integer
  has created_at, type: :timestamp
  has updated_at, type: :timestamp

  has start_date, type: :timestamp
  has end_date, type: :timestamp

end
```

My `question` property was previously called `description`. I thought that running:

```
heroku run bundle exec flying-sphinx rebuild
```

Would be enough to update my indexes (it was enough on my local machine), but it didn't seem to help.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Suspecting that is might have something to do with the DDoS attack on DNSSimple, seems like flying-sphinx.com is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNSimple downtime certainly didn't help.

Also, you want to run regenerate rather than rebuild given you're using real-time indices:

```
heroku run bundle exec flying-sphinx regenerate
```